# sudoが使えない環境下へのMeCabのインストール

Tags: macos, mecab

管理者権限がない環境で、MeCabをインストールしています。
[こちら](http://qiita.com/kadotami/items/57bc2fbb5132b79c7efe)と、[こちら](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/hase1031/20111005/1317808636)の記事を参考に(特に後者)、Mecab本体に関しては

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/S/usr/local --with-charset=utf8 --enable-utf8-only ; make ; make install
```

辞書に関しては、

```
$ ./configure --with-mecab-config=/home/S/usr/local/bin/mecab-config --prefix=/home/S/usr/local --with-charset=utf8 --with-dicdir=/home/S/usr/local/mecab-dic/ipadic-utf8 ; make ; make install
```

としてインストールを行い、`.bash_profile`にも

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/S/usr/local/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH:/home/S/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

としてPATHを通しているのですが、エラーがでます。

具体的には、辞書のインストールで、`make`をした段階で、

```
/home/S/usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d . -o . -f EUC-JP -t utf8
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmecab.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /home/S/usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index
  Reason: image not found
make: *** [matrix.bin] Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

というエラーができて完了できません。

ターミナルで`mecab` と実行しても、

```
$ mecab
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmecab.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /home/S/usr/local/bin/mecab
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

というほぼ同様のエラーが出ます。

`libmecab.2.dylib`自体は`/home/S/usr/local/lib/`に入っているのですが、実行時に`/usr/local/lib/`が参照されているのが原因のようです。

この場合、どうような修整を施せば良いのでしょうか。`dylib`の[安易な変更への注意](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/kento_1218/20101224/1293189590)もあり、対応に困っております。

環境は、

- iMac
- OS X El Capitan

です。

Comment: suコマンドは使えないのですか？

Comment: 試してみましたが、使えませんでした。

Comment: OSX の場合、`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ではなく `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` を使うのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @argus まずパスを直して初めから`make clean`をしてやり直しました。初めにポストしていたエラーは確かに出なくなりましたが、辞書の`make install`部分で`./model.def is not found. skipped. 
reading ./._Noun.nai.csv ... dictionary.cpp(316) [n == 5] format error:  
make: *** [matrix.bin] Error 255`が出て、`$ mecab`と実行させても`param.cpp(69) [ifs] no such file or directory: /home/S/usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic/dicrc`となります

Answer (score 3, accepted):

１: 元々の問題
何回かインストールを試すうちにおかしくなっていたようなので、まず`/home/S/usr/local/`の諸々のファイルを削除し、再インストール前に`make clean`をしてから、上の手順に沿ってMeCab本体と辞書をインストールした。
つまり、MeCab本体なら、解凍先フォルダに`cd`で移動して、

```
$ make clean ; ./configure --prefix=/home/S/usr/local --with-charset=utf8 --enable-utf8-only ; make ; make install
```

となる。

また、@argusさんのご指摘通り、`DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`と修正したものを`.bash_profile`では使用。

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/S/usr/local/bin
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$PATH:/home/S/usr/local/lib
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

2: コメントに書いた問題
これは、私の使っている環境で`._`から始まるファイルが自動で作られていたことが問題だった。ダウンロードした辞書を解凍したフォルダにターミナルから`cd`で移動して、`$ rm ._*.*`として不要なファイルを一括で削除し、`make clean`をして辞書のインストールを試せばOK。

3: 実行
ちなみに、実行の際には

```
$ clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ `mecab-config --cflags` sample.cpp  `mecab-config --libs`
```

のようにすればOK。

補足:
mecab-ipadic-neologdの利用は、[サイト](https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd/wiki/ProgrammingLanguage.ja)通りで問題ない。